# What is the suitable component for loading large files in Swing framework

Tags: java, swing, text-editor

I want to develop an Text Editor (like Editplus/textpad/Notepad) using java Swing components.First of all I use JTextArea to write/store the text.In JTextArea,no facility for different colors for keywords.That's why I changed to JTextPane.In this,The problem is when I load large file It takes more than a minute time to load.I want know the Which component in swing package to support all features to develop an text Editor.Please help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look to [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) (quote from javadocs: "a text component to edit various kinds of content").

And a nice tutorial: [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Comment: JEditorPane also taking more then a minute time to load large data files.please suggest something rather than the JTextArea/JEditorPane/JTextPane components or better of three for all features.

Comment: Then i suggest you to change language. Java Swing is slow, specially the text components.

If you want to use styled text, then you have to use JTextPane, and this one has a well-deserved reputation for being slow. All you can do is to use various techniques to make'it faster, but will never be as fast as those programs specified by you.

Comment: I'll give you another idea to check. Go download IntelliJ IDEA and/or NetBeans and try to open/edit your test file. These are some of the best IDEs written in Java (Eclipse is using SWT) and if you see your test file is still slow to open/edit then i doubt you will find something better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code to provide for this (I'm expecting to attempt to tackle a similar problem soon, so if I do end up with some code I might be able to add it), but conceptually the problem is solvable. Being written in Java and using Swing doesn't make this unsolvable and it's a poor excuse to give. Swing gets a bad rep because people don't understand the difference between functionality be condensed into a form that requires few lines to execute and you still need understand how GUIs work - which isn't even specific to Java GUIs, and between functionality being abstracted away. Two very different things and Swing does the former.

What you'll want is something to the effect of a [BasicScrollBarUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html). You'll have two things to work out: first is to lazily load the file, and second it to show scrollbars that give the appearance of having the whole file loaded.

### Lazy Loading

For lazily loading, I think the functions you might want to pay particular attention to is [#scrollByBlock(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html#scrollByBlock(int)) and [#scrollByUnit(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html#scrollByUnit(int)). In your UI you will likely need some attempt to cache and buffer a section of the file with some of the file above and below your currently displayed pane is stored into memory. When your two aforementioned functions get called, you should be able to (in a background worker thread, see [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)) load more of the file as you need it lazily.

### Faking out the scroll bar

For painting scrollbars as if the entire file is loaded I might know less about (as I said, I haven't taken a stab at solving this myself yet). The functions that appear to be useful here are likely to be [#paintThumb(Graphics, JComponent, Rectangle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html#paintThumb(java.awt.Graphics,%20javax.swing.JComponent,%20java.awt.Rectangle)) and [#setThumbBounds(int,int,int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicScrollBarUI.html#setThumbBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). It's going to end up being some combination of figuring out how large the file is, and performing some simple math to figure out how large the scrollbars should be. You might be able to just extract that logic from some existing implementation, where as the existing implementation will be scaling scrollbars based on size of text in the area and you are merely changing the size to be based on number of lines in a file. The painting will be how to paint the scrollbar in a location that corresponds to a location in the file, instead of location on the view port.

---

Graphically, in a minimal example, it will look like:

```
text above my viewport
-------viewport upper bound-------
line 1 in my view port
line 2 in my view port
line 3 in my view port
-------viewport lower bound-------
text below my viewport
```

and when you scroll down (for instance), you lazily load more of the file below the known line in a background thread, and your JTextArea/Pane/Editor edits up looking like:

```
line 1 in my view port
-------viewport upper bound-------
line 2 in my view port
line 3 in my view port
text below my viewport
-------viewport lower bound-------
newly loaded text from the worker thread
```

I'm interested in trying this myself for something I'm looking at, so it will be nice to see if this works.